# Is there any way to save char Array in For loop?

Tags: c#

I want to create a simple hangman and I'm stuck :/.
Here is simple code what detects all chars in the array.
I need some way to save it and then write it.
I add the comment in the code for more readability and where I want to save.
And at the end i need to write it.
Is there anything I could do better in code? I'm a newbie.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    char[] array;
    randomWord = "apple".ToCharArray();
    Console.WriteLine(randomWord);
    while (guessing == true) {


    Console.WriteLine();


    userinput = char.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    for (int i = 0; i < randomWord.Length; i++)
    {
        if (randomWord[i].ToString().Contains(userinput))
        {

        Console.Write(userinput);
        //add to array
         enter code here

        }
        else
        {
        //add to array
         enter code here
        Console.Write("_ ");
        }
    }
    //and here Write whole array
    for(int g = 0; g < array.Lenght; g++){
       Console.Write(array[g]);
    }
}
```

Comment: @DanielShillcock [it's ok to ask about homework](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/334823/542251)

Comment: @Liam Ah! I think the points regarding asking about homework questions still need to be followed in this case.

Comment: Its not my homework.Im learing on my own.Im not even at high school

Comment: Alex, have you been told to use char[] ? I wouldn't ... so to me it's a x-y-Question.

Comment: Yes, but "Make a good faith attempt to solve the problem yourself first. ". It's a simple task...

Comment: No i dont any idea to fix is welcome :)

Comment: Why not simple use a string:? if this is not homework... You will rarely use char array in c#

Comment: So, basically, you need to 1) get user input (single char at once) 2) check if char is in word 3) print word with all chars masked except for those already guessed by user. - So as Simo said, I'd use strings, not char[]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a [generic list (`List<T>`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=netframework-4.7.2) they are more flexible than arrays:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<char> array = new List<char>();
    randomWord = "apple".ToCharArray();
    Console.WriteLine(randomWord);
    while (guessing == true) {


        Console.WriteLine();


        userinput = char.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        for (int i = 0; i < randomWord.Length; i++)
        {
            if (randomWord[i].ToString().Contains(userinput))
            {

               Console.Write(userinput);
               //add to array
                array.Add(randomWord[i]);

            }
            else
            {
               //it's not clear what you want to add to here?
               Console.Write("_ ");
            }
        }
        //and here Write whole array
        //use a foreach
        foreach(char c in array ){
           Console.Write(c);
        }
    //your missing a brace
    }
}
```

Comment: "//it's not clear what you want to add to here?" - I guess he is trying to print one more part of the "hang man" , because the letter was not part of the word?

Comment: I want to add "_" something to do some space but that is already fix thanks :)